# Fetch all aws existing Lambda name dynamically in Cloud Formattion template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

We have a requirement to fetch existing Lambda Name in Cloud Formation Template and show in drop down.

I want to show fetched Lambda name as a dropdown in Cloud Formation Stack, Once users selects single/multiple Lambda function name's from Stack we will perform some operation on selected Lambda function.

I achieved second part via hard coding lambda names in cloud formation template, My question is for First Part fetch Lambda names dynamically in Cloud Formation Stack.

Comment: Could you try with AWS Custom Resources

Comment: Your second sentence is hard to understand. Could you please edit the question and clarify what you mean/ask?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Only a limited number of AWS-specific types can be automatically listed in a parameter field. AWS Lambda functions are *not* available.

See: [Parameters - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)

Comment: I don't think its not possible. There should be some work around to achieve same.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like one of the Parameters (displayed when launching a CloudFormation stack) to list existing Lambda functions?

Comment: I would like to display lambda names during Stack creation and provide a option to select same.

Comment: This is not possible. Lambda functions are not available as a parameter type. Custom Resources (which call a Lambda function to do processing outside of a CloudFormation template, such as selecting the latest AMI) only run once the stack is created, which is _after_ the parameters are displayed. Your only method would be to have some code modify the template file itself, to include the desired options, before requesting to create the stack.

Comment: No not possible.